# Analytically computable functions with behavior similar to the skew normal pdf

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm looking for a (computationally cheap) way to compute a function that behaves similar to the skew normal distribution, i.e. it has a shape like the normal distribution when some parameter `a = c`, while allowing to set some skew by varying `a`.

The background is that I'm using a Gaussian model for a shape manipulation tool but there are some edge cases that would be better served by an asymmetric function. Ideally, the function should be able to fit a positively shifted Gaussian G(x,mu,sigma), mu > 0 for the range of positive x.

Answer (score 0):

The logistic curve
$\dfrac1{1+e^{-ax}}
$
very closely matches
the cumulative normal distribution
especially if 
$a=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$,
which matches the slope
at the origin.
The maximum difference is
at most $0.017$.

Perhaps you can
modify this
to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Ill definitely try that.